# React Dropzone : need to pass id with file to upload

Tags: reactjs, dropzone, react-dropzone

I use [React Dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/) to upload files to my Node.js server.

When a file is dropped in the dropzone, the `handleOnDrop()` method is called. Then another `uploadPicture()` method is called.

```
...
handleOnDrop = (files) => {
    this.uploadPicture(files);
}

render() {
    const dropzone =
        <Dropzone onDrop={this.handleOnDrop}>
            {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                <section className="container">
                    <div {...getRootProps({ className: 'dropzone' })}>
                        <input {...getInputProps()} />
                        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
                    </div>
                </section>
            )}
        </Dropzone>
}

return (
    <div>
        <h1>Dropzone test</h1>
        {dropzone}
    </div>
}
...
```

1. I'm surprized with `file` argument : it is *known* by the `handleOnDrop()` method even if I do not pass it in this line `<Dropzone onDrop={this.handleOnDrop}>`. I do not understand where `file`is passed to the method.
2. I also do not understand the role of `getRootProps`, `getInputProps` inside the Dropzone. Maybe it is linked to the above question.
3. Finally, I would like to pass the id of the object whose I want to update the picture (the `<Dropzone>` will be in a `array.map(item => ())` and I will be able to access the `item.id`).

I tried this **non working code** and many variants, but I'm still not able to pass `item.id` to the `uploadPicture()` method.

```
handleOnDrop = (id, files) => {
    this.uploadPicture(id, files);
}

<Dropzone onDrop={() => this.handleOnDrop(item.id)}>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handleDrop` takes in two parameter but you are only passing in one,

You can try this instead:

```
<Dropzone onDropAccepted={(files) => this.handleOnDrop(files,item.id)}>
```

Comment: Thanks @Thanveer Shah it works perfectly with ```onDropAccepted```. Two more questions please... First : where did you find this method onDropAccepted please (I can not find documentation about it) ? Second question : is writing ```{(files) => this.handleOnDrop(files)}``` a shortcut to write ```{this.handleOnDrop}``` ? Thank you.

Comment: Its there in the doc , https://react-dropzone.js.org/ you can see it if you scroll down to Components. 
Yea you can, but in your case you are also passing an ID , so if you dont pass the files param, then you wont really be able to access it.